# How do I get rid of whitespace between sections CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web design and ran into this problem; I have two sections, each section with its won background image. However, the first background image doesn't end right after the previous background image. Instead, there's a whitespace between the two images that looks hideous.

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M26Ge/

CSS:

```
#slide-1 .bcg {
  background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Hopwas_Woods_Sun.jpg');  
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
#slide-2 .bcg{
  background-image:url('http://i953.photobucket.com/albums/ae11/Kronstadt/Shabby-Princess-Kristie_SF_StripedP.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure, but maybe are you looking for `CSS Reset`?

Just write `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` at top of css code. Else, if you are having other whitespace issues with inline elements, you can fix them using `font-size: 0;` on the container of the affected elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can as well hold the margin of `hx` and `p` elements within the section by

1. setting a border to the first child div . **[Borders](http://jsfiddle.net/M26Ge/22/)**

   `section>div {
       border:1px solid transparent
   }`
2. or **[padding](http://jsfiddle.net/M26Ge/23/)** will do:

   `section div  {
       padding:1px;
   }`

To understand what is going on , you can read **[this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This sets the margin and padding of all elements equal to zero.

Answer (score -1):

Using Sublime Text you have to place your elements right beside the other one.

```
<section>
 <div></div>
</section>
<section>
<div></div>
</section>
```

should become :

```
<section>
 <div></div>
</section><section>
 <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention Sublime Text in their question